# Django Password Recovery via Gmail [Errno 110] Connection timed out

Tags: python, django, smtp

I had a password recovery system via email in my web app, which was working perfectly before deployment. However, now that I have succesfully deployed, password recovery is the only feature that is not working, when solicited it stays loading for some time until the error `TimeoutError at /password-reset/ [Errno 110] Connection timed out`

Here is my `settings.py` file email configuration:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD =  config.get('EMAIL_PASS')
```

The credentials are tucked away into config file.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the port to my UFW firewall with `sudo ufw allow 587`. Also since I deployed through Linode (they currently have port 587 blocked for all users to prevent spam) I had to contact Linode Support, who then lifted the ban of port 587 on my Linode.

Answer (score 0):

Does sending emails other than the password reset work? If yes, what kind of email?

What platform is the app deployed on?

What service are you using to send emails?

Comment: Back when the app wasn't deployed, it would send an email with a link to reset the password. It used an account I created on gmail just for that purpose. However, now that I've deployed to a Linode Linux server it won't actually send the email anymore. From my understanding it uses SMTP and Gmail, and TLS is enabled.